# serve angularjs application hosted in cloudfoundry over https only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

i have an angularjs application that was hosted in ibm cloudfoundry my problem is that i need the app to be served only over https because i am using firebase messaging.
i have found a solution but the problem is that the navigator stuck because of too many redirections :

```js
var finalhandler = require('finalhandler')
var http = require('http')
var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
var port = (process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3001);
var host = (process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST || 'localhost');
var serve = serveStatic(__dirname+'/www')
var server = http.createServer(function onRequest (req, res) {
  if (req.secure) {
    serve(req, res, finalhandler(req, res))
  } else {
      res.writeHead(302, {'Location': 'https://'+req.headers.host + req.url});
      res.end();
  }
})
server.listen(port,host)
```

how to handle this problem please ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're purely serving static content, then you can use the staticfile buildpack.  The "force ssl" option will do exactly what you want.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/staticfile/index.html#config-process

To enable, you can run `cf set-env <your-app> FORCE_HTTPS true`, or add that environment variable to your cf cli manifest.yml file.

---

If you need to use the Node.js buildpack for some reason, then the trick is that you must look at either the `X-Forwarded-Proto` or `X-Forwarded-Port` headers.  For former you would check for `https` and the latter you would check for `443`.  Either would indicate that the connection is secure.

```
if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'https') {
  serve(req, res, finalhandler(req, res))
} else {
  res.writeHead(302, {'Location': 'https://'+req.headers.host + req.url});
  res.end();
}
```

If you're using Express, there is an option to do this automatically, `app.enable('trust proxy')`.

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html

Hope that helps!